# Visualising html5 audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm really interested in creating some sort of equaliser/visualiser to represent audio from my `<audio>` tag. So far I've been able to find several very fancy experiments that visualise audio. Most of them based on webgl, and only working in chrome. What I wan't to achieve is much more simpler than that, it's just a basic, one colour, 2d visualiser, nothing fancy.

This is something very similar to what I wan't to achieve (some sort of image in the middle and visualisation along the sides, very basic, yet I like it ;) )
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLRyAz0WFnw

The way I want it to work is to render/create visualisation based on src of audio tag, so for example

```
<audio id="test" 
src="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/78404260/stream?client_id=7a17129ba9cd5fff34f847e3539829b7">
</audio>
<!-- Some example from sound cloud -->
```

and there would be a canvas tag on the page which takes src from audio tag with certain id, in this case "test". I don't think something this simple should require usage of WebGl, and would like to instead use plain canvas, so it works in most browsers with html5 support. I'm a javascript newbie, so I don't know where to start. I mentioned several examples I found before, but looking at their source didn't help at all. I'm looking for elegant solution with nothing complex going on. I understand that stackoverflow is not for asking for complete code, so if you could just get me started, e.g. explain how to interact with audio, change size of those "equaliser sticks" depending on what is playing etc.. would be great ;)) (jQuery suggestions are also welcome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use Audio, but rather use the WebAudio Api.
Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge handles it, but IE do not.
(see here : http://caniuse.com/audio-api )
Beware webaudio is prefixed on Safari (webkit).

If you want a more global reach, SoundManager2 might be 
(one the possible) answer to your need, since it works on all browsers
with a flash fallback :
  http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

With WebAudio, This article explains how to get a frequency analysis
 in a quite simple way out of any track :
http://joshondesign.com/p/books/canvasdeepdive/chapter12.html

Comment: You mentioned support for Chrome and Safari, what about ff and ie? those two support <audio> tag, will they also work with api?

Answer (score 1):

There is a library that has emerged that does the low lever part of this called [dancer.js](https://github.com/jsantell/dancer.js) (and it has some killer demos).

My approach is not animated like you have requested, but the way I do this ([demo](http://fan.st/Joe90), press "play all songs") is to pre-generate a waveform when the song is uploaded, and use CSS (by setting the `background-image` of a waveform `div`).  This approach works surprisingly well.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what I'm asking for, I'm looking for something like this, but with help of js: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uG7x80uxp_c

Answer (score 0):

I created a cross-platform music equalizer, you can play an audio file while the equalization is on : you can see the tutorial and demo and download the source code from http://www.bestofjqueryplugins.com/plugins.php?name=jquery-music-equalizer

Comment: This is not a full equalizer. It only mimics the functionality

Comment: @BrassApparatus yes, the audio API wasn't available at the development time